# Rsync backups on btrfs very slow

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, hardlink, btrfs

My environment is Ubuntu 15.04 with kernel 3.19.0-28-generic and Btrfs v3.17.

I have two identical external USB hard disks that I use with my backup script. One of them is formatted with `btrfs` and the other one with `ext4`. The source filesystem is always `ext4`. The `rsync` command looks like this:

```
rsync --inplace --no-whole-file --link-dest="$previousBackup" "$sourceDir" "$destDir"
```

I just realized that the backup performed on `btrfs` takes an **extremely** long time: Slightly more than one hour, in comparison to the 4 minutes that it takes to perform the same copy to `ext4`.

To rule out disk malfunctioning I performed some benchmarks, with `dd` and the “disk utility” shipped with Ubuntu, but I have got the same performance on both disks. The slow part seems to be hardlinking against the previous backup. Even after a defrag and scrub, the following command takes around 53 minutes on `btrfs`, but only 1 minute on `ext4`:

```
cp -arl "$previousBackup" "$destDir"
```

By researching on the Internet, I found hints that the performance of `btrfs` suffers with hardlinks, but I would not expect this *huge* difference. I found out that this command is faster, but still takes over 30 minutes to complete:

```
cp -ar --reflink "$previousBackup" "$destDir"
```

Does anyone have experience with this behaviour and can confirm it? Is there any simple way to correct it (e.g. different mount options) or should I try to delete as many hardlinks as possible and just use reflinks?

EDIT

I just found out that even *deleting* a directory from `btrfs` requires more than one hour. The same operation is instantaneous on the "twin" `ext4` disk. There is obviously a problem with metadata here.

Comment: @JakeGould The number of files _linked_ is very large but the number of files _transferred_ from `ext4` to `btrfs` is usually small (200 or so). That is what I cannot explain: copy-on-write should make the _linking_ almost instantaneous (only metadata is processed) but the _transfer_ slightly slower... while here the opposite happens.

Comment: Is the filesystem, metadata segments in particular, anywhere full?  As I recall metadata performance gets pretty bad with limited space. Btrfs' default heuristics can also fail to allocate enough space for metadata.

Comment: @Tobu `btrfs filesystem df`reports
Data, single: total=1.34TiB, used=1.34TiB
System, DUP: total=8.00MiB, used=176.00KiB
System, single: total=4.00MiB, used=0.00B
Metadata, DUP: total=38.47GiB, used=37.49GiB
Metadata, single: total=8.00MiB, used=0.00B
Does not seem full to me... however, is there any way to tweak the space allocated for metadata?

Answer (score 0):

You say you are copying hardlinks with your [`rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) command, but where is the `-H` flag? I don’t see it in your command:

```
rsync --inplace --no-whole-file --link-dest="$previousBackup" "$sourceDir" "$destDir"
```

The way I understand how `rsync` works—with regards to hardlinks—is that without the `-H` flag actual data is copied instead of the hardlink as explained on the [`rsync` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync):

> **-H, --hard-links**
>
> This tells rsync to look for hard-linked files in the transfer and
>   link together the corresponding files on the receiving side. Without
>   this option, hard-linked files in the transfer are treated as though
>   they were separate files.

I can imagine such a procedure where many similar files are copied over and over instead of being hardlinked would add up to slower transfer time.

Also, consider using the `-z` (`--compress`) flag as well:

> **-z, --compress**
>
> With this option, rsync compresses the file data as it is sent to the
>   destination machine, which reduces the amount of data being
>   transmitted -- something that is useful over a slow connection.

Yes, this is a USB to USB transfer on the same system so it’s likely speed is already optimized, but it doesn’t hurt to see of `-z` will perhaps help you overcome natural USB data transfer bottlenecks.

A nice, simple tutorial that explains these flags—as well as others—[can be found here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apple-osx-bsd-rsync-copy-hard-links/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The `--hard-links` is used to _preserve_ hard links in the source directory. With the command I use `--link-dest` causes the destination directory to be hard-linked with the previous backup _on the same USB disk_. Essentially, that is a _differential_ backup, where only changed files are actually transferred from source, anything else is a long chain of hardlinks from backup to backup.

Comment: As for the `--compress` option, this is mostly useful for network transfers. One can test the difference, but with USB it is unlikely to bring any advantage, as the quicker transfer is probably balanced by the CPU time to compress the data. Either way, this does not address my case, as the options are the same for both `ext4` (which is fast) and `btrfs` (which is slow).